# convert html5 tags(with some classes) to div tags with same classes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that was created with HTML5 doctype, so it has

```
<header class="1-header"></header>
<footer class="1-footer"></footer>
```

Is it possible to convert them programatically to div tags with the same classes? Is there a library or piece of code that can do that?

```
<div class="1-header"></div>
<div class="1-footer"></div>
```

**Note: The idea is to use the html page developed with html5 doctype to work in XHTML doctype. Not worried about successful validation as of now.**

Also not worried too much about performance, since its going to be an offline tool to save some manual work of converting these tags.

Comment: Why would you want to convert the tags? If you want to provide support for older browsers you should try [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

Comment: Once a DOM element is created, its tag is immutable. You would need to create a new tag for each old tag and replace. jQuery's `replaceWith()` method might be of interest to you. http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/. If you want a quick drop in fix, @Sam is correct in suggesting html5shiv

Comment: If you have control of the backend, you could also try your hand at XSLT which would allow you to convert and serve as XHTML without tying up the browser with unnecessary DOM manipulations after rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through the objects in the page, for each element create a parallel one and set the new element's attributes to equal the old one's, then same for the data.

An example can be found here: http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-change-tag-name

Comment: You should note that this would be a resource hog on a larger page and would need to wait for DOMContentLoaded event so there would be a long delay before the user would see the page.

Comment: Agreed. You'd be much better off doing this manipulation server-side, or using a modernizer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, you can replace the elements with `div`s like so, bringing the classes along:

```
$('header, footer').each(
  function () {
    var el = $(this);

    var div = $('<div>').
      prop('class', el.prop('class'));
      // if you want other attributes, you'll need to add them the same way

    // move contents to the new container
    el.contents().appendTo(div);

    // and replace
    el.replaceWith(div);
  }
);
```

Although, of course, if the DOM is up and running well enough to run jQuery against the HTML5 elements, I'm not sure you need to change anything.